# Setup Nagios dependencies to monitor a service on a Windows host

Tags: windows, service, dependencies, nagios

I'm having difficulties setting up nagios dependencies so I only receive notifications if the host is up (Pingable).

My host cfg file is as follow:

```
# Configuration file /etc/nagios/adagios/hosts/dp-front.cfg
# Edited by PyNag on Wed Nov 11 16:38:15 2015

define host {
         alias                          Ditmas Park Front Desk
         use                            windows-server
         host_name                      dp-front
         address                        192.168.200.47
        max_check_attempts            2
        check_command                 check-host-alive
        check_period                  workhours
        notification_period           workhours
}

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               dp-front
        service_description     Medical Records
        check_command           check_nt!PROCSTATE!-d SHOWALL -l Robocopy.exe
        notification_interval         0
        max_check_attempts            1
        }

define servicedependency{
                host_name                       localhost
                service_description             PING
                dependent_host_name             localhost
                dependent_service_description   PING
                execution_failure_criteria      c
                notification_failure_criteria   w,u,c

                }
```

Nagios is monitoring the service correctly and I receive notifications all the time when the service go down. I'm just not sure how to setup the "servicedependency" section of it.

I'd really appreciate your help as always.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to setup below perameter in your host configuration file

**notification_options  d u r**

Comment: It's already setup
'execution_failure_criteria      u,c,p'
'notification_failure_criteria   u,c,p'

Answer (score 0):

Add to your host template `'windows-server'` a `notification_option` option

https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html

> notification_options: This directive is used to determine when
>   notifications for the host should be sent out. Valid options are a
>   combination of one or more of the following: d = send notifications on
>   a DOWN state, u = send notifications on an UNREACHABLE state, r = send
>   notifications on recoveries (OK state), f = send notifications when
>   the host starts and stops flapping, and s = send notifications when
>   scheduled downtime starts and ends. If you specify n (none) as an
>   option, no host notifications will be sent out. If you do not specify
>   any notification options, Nagios will assume that you want
>   notifications to be sent out for all possible states. Example: If you
>   specify d,r in this field, notifications will only be sent out when
>   the host goes DOWN and when it recovers from a DOWN state.